# LinkedIn API error when retrieving UCG Posts by Author

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm making a call to the LinkedIn API to retrieve the full list of posts by my organization but keep getting the error;

`Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/authors]`

I believe I have all the necessary permissions (**r_organization_social** to be specific);

`r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social`

Here's my request;

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List({COMPANY_URN_URLENCODED})&oauth2_access_token={LINKEDIN_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

It's the same result if the URN *isn't* URL encoded.

I'm following steps here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#find-ugc-posts-by-authors

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3Acompany_id)&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED

Replace `company_id` with your company id

I have used this as my api call to retrieve my company posts.

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.